# Combining forms into a single tex document

Tags: forms

I am a chemist and would like to make a form for my daily experiments.  I am able to create said form and my questions is can I combine all the forms into one document i.e. a lab notebook. I know that I can email the form to myself is there a better ''action'' command that I can use so that the submit button will put the newly created form into a master `.tex` file?

FYI this code is for my running log not my lab notebook.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[width=250mm, top=25mm,
       bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=1cm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,margin=1cm]{caption}





\newdimen\longline
\longline=\textwidth\advance\longline-4cm

\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2} % override default in hyperref


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{Form}

\begin{tabular}{l@{}*5l@{}}
\toprule[1.5pt]
Date & Route & Time(min) & Weather& Comments \\ 
\midrule

\TextField[name=date1, width=1.5cm] \enspace{} & \TextField[name=route1, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{} & \TextField[name=time1, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}&\ChoiceMenu[name=weather, width=2cm] {}{ Good=g, Fair=f, Poor=p} & \TextField[height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}   \\ 
\midrule

\TextField[name=date2, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}& \TextField[name=route2, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{} & \TextField[name=time2, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}&\ChoiceMenu[name=weather, width=2cm] {}{ Good=g, Fair=f, Poor=p} & \TextField[height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}   \\ 
\midrule

\TextField[name=date3, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}& \TextField[name=route3, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{} & \TextField[name=time3, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}&\ChoiceMenu[name=weather, width=2cm] {}{ Good=g, Fair=f, Poor=p} & \TextField[height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}   \\ 
\midrule

\TextField[name=date4, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}& \TextField[name=route4, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{} & \TextField[name=time4, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}&\ChoiceMenu[name=weather, width=2cm] {}{ Good=g, Fair=f, Poor=p} & \TextField[height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}   \\ 
\midrule

\TextField[name=date5, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}& \TextField[name=route5, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{} & \TextField[name=time5, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}&\ChoiceMenu[name=weather, width=2cm] {}{ Good=g, Fair=f, Poor=p} & \TextField[height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}   \\ 

\midrule
\TextField[name=date6, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}& \TextField[name=route6, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{} & \TextField[name=time6, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}&\ChoiceMenu[name=weather, width=2cm] {}{ Good=g, Fair=f, Poor=p} & \TextField[height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}   \\ 
\midrule
\TextField[name=date7, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}& \TextField[name=route7, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{} & \TextField[name=time7, height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}&\ChoiceMenu[name=weather, width=2cm] {}{ Good=g, Fair=f, Poor=p} & \TextField[height=0.01cm, width=1.5cm] \enspace{}   \\ 

\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{Form}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This sounded fascinating. However, I guess there's a typo in your subject line, which is rather disappointing.

Comment: Some of us are dyslexic which is also disappointing.

Comment: by the way, you tex file is not executable because you are missing a curly bracket at the end of the form.

Comment: That should work.  Thanks for the help everyone